# what is the purpose of the command "COPY ./ ." in Linux?

Tags: docker

I just saw a command when built a docker image as below

```
COPY ./ .
```

I know the parameter "./" which used in Linux or Unix to execute a complied program in the current directory. And the parameter "."  present the current directory.

I just confused what is the real purpose of the command `COPY ./ .`?

Copy the current directory content to current directory?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1: Copy the current directory content to current directory?

No, absolutely NOT

> 2: What is `COPY ./ .` ?

The COPY instruction takes at least two arguments. The last argument is the destination, and all other arguments are source files

```
Syntax: COPY [<src> | <src>] <dest>

COPY ./ .
      ^ ^         
      | |_ #=> place the file where the image is being built, into the build container
      |
    copy all files from HOST current dir
```

> 3:  what is the real purpose of the command "COPY"?

- The COPY instruction will copy files (say your source code, or hello program) from the filesystem where the image is being built, into the build container.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Docker command, not a Linux command.

From the [Docker manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy):

> The COPY instruction copies new files or directories from <src> and adds them to the filesystem of the container at the path <dest>.

The purpose is to copy all files from the build context (usually the directory on the host that contains the Dockerfile) into the container.

(For reference, the GNU/Linux command to copy files is `cp`)